# Its says: cannot resolve symbol 'create'

Tags: android

What is wrong in following **create** method of `MediaPlayer`? I have passed the required parameters correctly.

```
import android.media.MediaPlayer;

public class Splash extends Activity {

    MediaPlayer intro;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle sScreen) {
        super.onCreate(sScreen);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash);

        intro = new MediaPlayer.create(Splash.this, R.raw.tingting);
        intro.start();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause(){
        super.onPause();
        intro.release();
        finish();

    }
}
```

Comment: Your brackets seem to be wrong

Comment: thats when im copying the code from ide i have made a mistake but thats not main issue... this i cannot use this create method

Comment: You should also remove the `new` keyword

Comment: oh thank you so much ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`create()` is a [Factory method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern).

> [Creating the object] is done by by calling a factory method [...] rather than by calling a constructor.

You do not need to call `new`, this is done automatically by `MediaPlayer.create`:

```
intro = MediaPlayer.create(Splash.this, R.raw.tingting);
```